# How to hide an specific field from result in strongloop

Tags: javascript, rest, strongloop

I'm trying to create an project using strongloop, in which I'm creating an web service for user login, My code runs well & gets desired output except the fact that it does not hide password

I'm getting result as

```
{
    "result": [{
        "_id": 2,
        "address": "abc",
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_date": "2016-03-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        "firstname": "Anup",
        "isdeleted": 0,
        "lastname": "Deshpande",
        "mobile_number": "9700128907",
        "oldpassword": "string",
        "profile_picturename": "anup.jpeg",
        "role_id": 1,
        "user_email_id": "anupd@ideaentity.com",
        "user_password": "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8",
        "user_status": 1
    }]
}
```

Where I want to hide or delete `"user_password": "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"`, field.

can anyone tell me how can i do that in strongloop's remote method

My renote method code is like follows

```
db.collection('users').find({
                user_email_id : par,
                user_password : sha256(par2)
            }).toArray(function(err, result) {

                // var passwordHash = hashPassword(user_password);
                // console.log(passwordHash);
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    self.callback(null, result);
                    // db.disconnect();
                } else {
                    self.callback(null, response);
                    // db.disconnect();
                }
            });
```

Here "result will give all details" I want to hide password from result

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
{ fields: {propertyName: <true|false>, propertyName: <true|false>, ... } }
```

> propertyName is the name of the property (field) to include or
>   exclude.  signifies either true or false Boolean literal. 
>   Use true to include the property or false to exclude it from results.
>   You can also use 1 for true and 0 for false. By default, queries
>   return all model properties in results.  However, if you specify at
>   least one fields filter with a value of true, then by default the
>   query will include only those you specifically include with filters.

refer this link
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Fields+filter

```
Example:
var query = { fields: {password: false} }
Model.find(query, function()
{
});
```

> Otherwise you can manually remove in afterremotemethod(), in 
>   ctx.result.
>   refer this link https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks

Comment: Please check updated question & can you tell me how can i filters fields with result in my code line "self.callback(null, result);"

Comment: Did you get? also check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

> Add hidden field in you model.json  that is  "hidden": ["password",
>   "verificationToken"],

```
Example:
{
  "name": "User",
  "properties": {
    "realm": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "credentials": {
      "type": "object",
      "deprecated": true
    },
    "challenges": {
      "type": "object",
      "deprecated": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "emailVerified": "boolean",
    "verificationToken": "string",
    "status": "string",
    "created": "date",
    "lastUpdated": "date"
  },
  "options": {
    "caseSensitiveEmail": true
  },
  "hidden": ["password", "verificationToken"],
  "acls": [

  ],
  "relations": {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me

// {user_password:0} - to hide password

```
db.collection('users').find({
                user_email_id : par,
                user_password : sha256(par2)
            },{user_password:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
```

this worked fine

for mare details you can check [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)